# Как вывести изображение с ПК через HDMI на ноутбук?

Tags: linux, видео, hdmi

Необходимо, чтобы мой видеовыход на ноуте работал как видеовход.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

теоретически, конечно, где-то в природе существуют видео-адаптеры, которые умеют использовать один и тот же физический интерфейс (выполненный по стандарту hdmi, к примеру) и для получения и для передачи аудио-видео-информации.

но у вас скорее всего самые обычные адаптеры, которые используют данные интерфейсы только для передачи аудио-видео-информации, и не умеют её по такому интерфейсу получать.

потому ответ на ваш вопрос прост и лаконичен: **никак**.